# MongoDB native driver for Node.js is not returning a result when querying '_id'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to query my database for a matching '_id' but the results are coming back null, but in the mongodb shell it is coming back with the correct results. Here is the code I am using.

```
var collection = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'products');
collection.findOne({ _id : 50738ebbe3d87c6beaddb6f2 }, function(err, result){
  res.send(result);
  console.log(result);
});
```

I've also tried using,

```
"ObjectId('50738ebbe3d87c6beaddb6f2')"
```

but that also come back 'null'.

Comment: { _id : '50738ebbe3d87c6beaddb6f2' } does adding quotes work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
collection.findOne({ _id : new mongodb.ObjectID('50738ebbe3d87c6beaddb6f2') }, 
  function(err, result){
    res.send(result);
    console.log(result);
  }
);
```

Comment: This works, thank you so much. Where would I have found the documentation on this? There is not a lot of documentation on the native mongodb driver.

Comment: @CollinMcGuire Full documentation is available [here](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html).  Note: github is having issues right now so it's not available at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This will works fine.
You can use BSON for get ObjectID from HEX string.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var BSON = mongodb.BSONNative;

var o_id = BSON.ObjectID.createFromHexString(theidID);
collection.findOne({'_id' : o_id}, function(err, document) {
 console.log(document);
});
```